# How to create Dynamic Header with different Column In SQL Server using Pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table structure. I want to  2 Header for Different Table columns Using Pivot. Also I have mention my expected output.

```
Table : 1
tblProject

ProhectId    ProjectName Intime  OutTime
934            AYX       540     1020
935            ABC       540     1020  
936            XYZ       540     1020
937            QWE       540     1020
938            RTY       480     1020

table 2

tblCode

Id     ProhectId      Code 
1        934            ABC001 
2        935            XYZ002 
3        936            255000 
4        937            789654 
5        938            458922
```

I Have Tried too result with

```
select * from (select sum((convert(decimal,OutTime - InTime))/60)  as TotalTime, ProjectName from tblProject  group BY ProjectName)
src pivot(Max(src.TotalTime) for src.ProjectName in (AYX,ABC,XYZ,QWE,RTY)) piv
```

I am not able to Pivot of 2nd Table with New header of Project Code.

Expected Output:

```
Project Name    AYX     ABC      XYZ    QWE     RTY
code            ABC001  XYZ002  255000  789654  458922
                 8(Hours)     8       8      8       9
```

Comment: But I Use 2 Table....and want 2 Header for  Project Name and Project Code

Comment: @Ramakrishna Jadhav: First join those two tables and fetch your required output. Second You can't have multiple headers as you would in excel but you can pre-concatenate your headers instead.

Comment: Please can you give me the example??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42536325/tsql-pivot-with-multiple-column-headers